# Google Sheets VLOOKUP inconsistent naming issue

Tags: google-sheets

How would I use VLOOKUP or a similar function to search another sheet with a similar but different name i.e. "Ben Matthews" in Sheet 1 is called "Matthews" in Sheet 2, along with 2 other "Matthews", so partial Lookup does not work, simply changing the names also isn't viable, as there is 100+ names and the Sheet is updated weekly with new data, which would require manually changing names every week.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Just to clarify... Are you saying that Sheet2 contains three instances of "Matthews" but only one instance relates to "Ben Matthews"; the other  two instances might relate to one OR two other persons?